# procmon - reset "relative time"

Tags: sysinternals

**procmon** allows to add column *Ralative Time* (since the start of profiling).

I want to measure distance between recorded events and  it would be trivial if I can reset relative time to zero at some point.

Is it possible to reset *Relative Time* to zero for the event (and readjust surrounding values of cause!)?

Comment: That would mean that previous entries will become negative. This is unlikely to be possible.

Comment: Wireshark supports this. I see no problem unless implementation doesn't suport it. Which is the question...